# magento: products not showing up on the frontend : no code

Tags: categories, product, magento

I'm still new to learning Magento. I only followed a tutorial but it's not working. I added a new product and associated it to all categories just as a test. The tutorial would show the image of the product once he clicks on a subcategory but mine didn't.

It gives me this error:

> The requested URL /magento/sample-sub-cat-1-tutorials/sample-sub-category-2.html was not found on this server.

What is wrong? I'm doing everything in the admin panel without coding as a start.

Comment: Have you done Index Management ? If not please do and check.
-
Thanks.

Comment: i already did.. it's not showing up anymore on that notification bar

Comment: `/magento/sample-sub-cat-1-tutorials/sample-sub-category-2.html` does not sound right, which tutorial are you following (link it). Clear your Cache _might_ work, but I think your trying to access the wrong link.

Comment: Is this a magento or a server generated error? You may not have mod_rewrite/.htaccess config properly. Try www.xyz.com/index.php/magento/sample-sub...

Comment: i simply clicked on a subcategory named "sample_sub_category2" under the root category named "sample_sub_cat1_tutorials"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an error page returned by your web server software, not a Magento-handled 404 page. Try adding index.php before your url string i.e. `site.com/index.php/magento/sample-sub-cat-1-tutorials/sample-sub-category-2.html`; if that works, you need to check server rewrites (System > Configuration > Web > Search Engines Optimization) or check that rewriting is available for your web server software.